# Can I use a composite primary key as the index in a free text index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a FREE TEXT INDEX for the first time.  This is what I have:

```
create table Person (
   ID int identity not null, 
   [type] int not null, 
   Notes nvarchar(1000), 
   CONSTRAINT [PersonPK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID,[type])
)

insert into Person ([type], Notes) values (1, 'Attended a football match')
insert into Person ([type], Notes) values (1, 'Went to the cinema')
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person(Notes)   
   KEY INDEX PersonPK   
   WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

The error I see is:

> Msg 7653, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
> 'PersonPK' is not a valid index to enforce a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique, non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, does not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full-text key.

I believe this is because I am using a composite primary key.  This runs:

```
create table Person (ID int identity not null, [type] int not null, Notes nvarchar(1000), CONSTRAINT [PersonPK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC))
    insert into Person ([type], Notes) values (1, 'Attended a football match')
    insert into Person ([type], Notes) values (1, 'Went to the cinema')
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PersonIndex ON Person(ID);  
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;  
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person(Notes)   
       KEY INDEX PersonIndex   
       WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

and then this works as expected i.e. returns one row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person
WHERE CONTAINS(Notes,'football') ;
```

The problem is that the Person table contains a composite primary key. Entity.ID is unique so I believe my solution will work, however can I use a composite primary key as the index? I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: *"I believe this is because I am using a composite primary key"* This is *exactly* the reason: `A full-text search key must be a ... single-column index which is not offline...`

Comment: Of all the error messages we could complain about for being unclear, this isn't one of them, it tells you precisely what constraints the index must meet. Note that there is no requirement for the index to be the primary key, you are free to create another one that does meet the requirements -- as you yourself demonstrate. The message is in fact so exact that it tells you a deterministic computed column would be allowed, and you could create one of those based on your columns and index that.

Comment: Create a computed column `ID_type AS (CAST(ID AS bigint) * 4294967296 + type)`

Comment: Generally speaking, an identity column is unique within a table. Adding an additional column to that will not make a row "more unique". So the better question is why you choose to define the primary key in this fashion. I suspect a modelling problem here. Usually a "person" is more than just a type and a note.